# Adding numbers in a string using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a string (in a variable) that has a list of numbers separated by space or comma.
I need to sum the numbers in the string.
example string "1,2,5,12,3"
or "1 2 5 12 3"

Is there a way to add the numbers within the string and return the total?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, very short and easy XSLT 1.0 solution. :)

Comment: An even shorter, complete XSLT 2.0 solution added. My answer now provides explanations for both solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This much shorter transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="sumStringList">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pSum" select="0"/>
  <xsl:param name="pDelim" select="','"/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not(string-length($pText) >0)">
     <xsl:value-of select="$pSum"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:variable name="vnewList"
         select="concat($pText,$pDelim)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vHead" select=
     "substring-before($vnewList, $pDelim)"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="sumStringList">
     <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
     "substring-after($pText, $pDelim)"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="pSum" select="$pSum+$vHead"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="pDelim" select="$pDelim"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>1,2,5,12,3</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
23
```

**Explanation**: Recursively called named template that also matches a text node. A sentinel (appended comma) is added to speed up and streamline processing.

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:param name="pDelim" select="','"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "sum(for $s in tokenize(.,$pDelim)
         return number($s)
        )
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the same XML document (above), this transformation produces the same wanted, correct answer**:

```
23
```

Here we use the standard XPath 2.0 function [**`tokenize()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) and we must convert every resulting token to number (using the [**`number()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-number) function) before finally applying the standard XPath function [**`sum()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-sum).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know XSLT, but generally you would split the string using spaces and commas as separators.
After a quick search I found that you can use *tokenize(string, separator)* as the split function if you are using XSLT 2.0. [This page](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/05/07/tr.html) has an example on how to use *tokenize*.

Comment: Just adding, you can also use tokenize with EXSLT if your processor doesn't support XSLT 2.0 (I had similar issues in the past)

Comment: The complete XSLT/XPath 2.0 code would be `sum(for $s in tokenize('1,2,5,12,3', ',') return number($s))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an XSLT 1.0 solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:variable name="listOfValues" select="'1,2,5,12,3'" />

        <xsl:call-template name="splitAndAdd">
            <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$listOfValues"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="splitAndAdd">
        <xsl:param name="list" />
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
        <xsl:param name="total" select="0" />

        <xsl:variable name="newList">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($list)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space($list),$delimiter)" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="token" 
                      select="substring-before($newList, $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:variable name="remaining" 
                      select="normalize-space(substring-after($newList, $delimiter))" />

        <xsl:variable name="newTotal" select="$total + number($token)" />

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$remaining">
                <xsl:call-template name="splitAndAdd">
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$remaining"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="total" select="$newTotal" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$newTotal" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>     

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you but thesolution seems to bring back a list of the numbers without the delimter (not the total).